# Taking script of filtered stored procedures

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I want to take script of stored procedures in SQL Server 2008  the problem is in my application there are more than 2000 stored procedures but I want stored procedures which are updated before ten days only and I want to take script of it how can I do this. I know using scripting wizard but want to select each stored procedures from it. Is there any easier method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query - it should work in SQL Server 2005 and up:

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    p.create_date,
    p.modify_date,
    sm.definition
FROM 
    sys.procedures AS p
INNER JOIN 
    sys.sql_modules AS sm ON p.object_id = sm.object_id
WHERE 
    p.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND p.modify_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -10, DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE())
```

It will show you the name, creation date, last modify date, and the T-SQL code of the stored procedures

Comment: @NIGHIL DAS: with my query, you do get the definition (T-SQL code) of the stored proc

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEDIFF(D,modify_date, GETDATE()) < 10
```